# MacOs terminal issue with zsh

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh, macos-big-sur

Yesterday i have updated my MacOS from catalina to big sur.
Whenever i open terminal i am getting below errors.

```
Last login: Sat Nov 14 17:54:05 on ttys000
/Users/amolbhure/.zshrc:6: no such file or directory: source~/.bash_profile
/Users/amolbhure/.zshrc:104: compinit: function definition file not found
/Users/amolbhure/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh:78: compinit: function definition file not found
/Users/amolbhure/.oh-my-zsh/lib/completion.zsh:75: bashcompinit: function definition file not found
No version set for command direnv
Consider adding one of the following versions in your config file at /Users/amolbhure/.tool-versions
direnv 2.23.1
/Users/amolbhure/.zshrc:113: compinit: function definition file not found
/Users/amolbhure/.zshrc:117: compinit: function definition file not found
/Users/amolbhure/.zshrc:121: compinit: function definition file not found
No version set for command direnv
Consider adding one of the following versions in your config file at /Users/amolbhure/.tool-versions
direnv 2.23.1
/Users/amolbhure/.zshrc:126: compinit: function definition file not found
/Users/amolbhure/.zshrc:130: compinit: function definition file not found
/Users/amolbhure/.zshrc:134: compinit: function definition file not found
/Users/amolbhure/.zshrc:138: compinit: function definition file not found
/Users/amolbhure/.zshrc:142: compinit: function definition file not found
/Users/amolbhure/.zshrc:146: compinit: function definition file not found
/Users/amolbhure/.zshrc:150: compinit: function definition file not found
/Users/amolbhure/.zshrc:154: compinit: function definition file not found
/Users/amolbhure/.zshrc:158: compinit: function definition file not found
/Users/amolbhure/.zshrc:162: compinit: function definition file not found
/Users/amolbhure/.zshrc:166: compinit: function definition file not found
/Users/amolbhure/.zshrc:170: compinit: function definition file not found
/Users/amolbhure/.zshrc:174: compinit: function definition file not found
/Users/amolbhure/.zshrc:178: compinit: function definition file not found
/Users/amolbhure/.zshrc:182: compinit: function definition file not found
/Users/amolbhure/.zshrc:186: compinit: function definition file not found
/Users/amolbhure/.zshrc:190: compinit: function definition file not found
/Users/amolbhure/.zshrc:194: compinit: function definition file not found
/Users/amolbhure/.zshrc:198: compinit: function definition file not found
/Users/amolbhure/.zshrc:202: compinit: function definition file not found
/Users/amolbhure/.zshrc:206: compinit: function definition file not found
/Users/amolbhure/.zshrc:210: compinit: function definition file not found
/Users/amolbhure/.zshrc:214: compinit: function definition file not found
/Users/amolbhure/.zshrc:218: compinit: function definition file not found
/Users/amolbhure/.zshrc:222: compinit: function definition file not found
/Users/amolbhure/.zshrc:226: compinit: function definition file not found
/Users/amolbhure/.zshrc:230: compinit: function definition file not found
/Users/amolbhure/.zshrc:234: compinit: function definition file not found
/Users/amolbhure/.zshrc:238: compinit: function definition file not found
➜  ~
```

I am not able to type anything.
If i type any keyword from computer it throws me below error, and it keep goes like that. so frustrating.

```
-zsh:1: url-quote-magic: function definition file not found
```

Comment: You obviously have in your .zshrc a line which says `source~/.bash_profile`. First of all, remove this line. For the subsequent error, the message tells you where exactzly  the error occurs, so I wonder why you hide this information from us .....

Answer (score 6):

I don't exactly know the root cause of this, but I got around it by uninstalling and reinstalling oh-my-zsh.

The trickiest part was getting any shell to work.  I ended up needing to load `/bin/bash` in my Terminal. Preferences > General > "Shells open with:" > command `/bin/bash`

Once I could run bash I removed oh-my-zsh

`rm -rf ~/.oh-my-zsh`

After that I could immediately reinstall it:

`sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/master/tools/install.sh)"`

Backup your `.zshrc` first just in case!